# How to show only parts or regions that have changed in VS Code Diff

Tags: visual-studio-code, diff, jetbrains-ide

IntelliJ IDEs have a button called "Collapse Unchanged Fragments", which hides most code lines that have stayed the same and fit the relevant information in way less space. Is there something similar in VS Code? If so, how do you enable it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's been implemented now. See this comment https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3562#issuecomment-1609725434

```
"diffEditor.experimental.useVersion2": true,
"diffEditor.experimental.collapseUnchangedRegions": true,
```

Comment: Be sure to restart your editor for these changes to take effect.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be impossible in VS Code. The feature has been requested here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3562. But at the current moment, it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: The request has been open for 6 years with hundreds of upvotes already without an implementation so you could simply assume it's not going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Just to update the accepted answer.  In Stable v1.82 are these settings and keybindings:

```
Diff Editor > Hide Unchanged Regions: Enabled
Diff Editor > Hide Unchanged Regions: Context Line Count
Diff Editor > Hide Unchanged Regions: Minimum Line Count
Diff Editor > Hide Unchanged Regions: Reveal Line Count
```

[image: settings to hide unchanged regions in a diff editor]

```
Diff Editor > Experimental: Use Version2   // now defaults to enabled/true
```

and these keyboard shortcuts:

```
Diff Editor: Collapse All Unchanged Regions
diffEditor.collapseAllUnchangedRegions

Diff Editor: Show All Unchanged Regions
diffEditor.showAllUnchangedRegions

diffEditor.toggleCollapseUnchangedRegions
```

These three keyboard shortcuts are unbound by default and can be found by searching for "unchanged" in the Keyboard Shortcuts editor.

You can also use the mouse to fold or expand unchanged regions as shown in the demo below.  Or double-click on the text `nnn hidden lines` to unfold.

And also drag the sash bar just above or below the `nnn hidden lines` text to reveal more of the hidden code.

[image: unchanged region handling in a diff editor by mouse]

---

And there is a toggle collapse/expand unchanged regions button when you have a diff open:

[image: toggle collapsing unchanged regions button]